# Who should NOT file income tax return in India?

Tags: income-tax, india

I know farmers are exempt from paying income tax but they voluntarily may file Income Tax Return if they want to. If they hadn't then trillions wouldn't have been [laundered](https://www.thequint.com/india/2016/03/19/even-as-farmers-die-trillions-laundered-as-agricultural-income).

Now I know seniors whose income in a financial year is less than INR 250000, there ITR is not accepted. I know this as an uncle of mine went whose only income is bank interest and the amount was pretty less than that and his ITR was not accepted.

Are there any individuals whose income is less than INR 250000 who don't have to file Income Tax Return. I stated INR 250000 as that is from where the Income Tax slab [starts](http://www.incometaxindia.gov.in/charts%20%20tables/tax%20rates.htm).

I am looking at small businesses like hair-dressers, bhel [vendors](http://www.gettyimages.ca/detail/photo/bhel-puri-vendors-cart-high-res-stock-photography/150384840) etc. It would be nice if somebody can share a link, preferably from Income Tax Dept. which states if there are any individuals who do not have to file income tax return (apart from seniors).

Comment: Shirish, the question is not clear. What are you trying to get at? There is a guide as to who needs to file an ITR. Any one who does not meet the guideline is not required to file.

Comment: @Dheer where is this guide, I haven't seen it, please share the link to the guide. Sorry didn't see your comment for some reason sooner.

Answer (score 1):

Anyone who has taxable income or is expecting refund, needs to file an ITR. Others may choose to file or not to file.

> Now I know seniors whose income in a financial year is less than INR 250000, there ITR is not accepted

This is incorrect. One can choose to file NIL returns [even with zero amount] or whatever amount in the return even if there is no tax due.

Comment: Is this something which happened recently (digital way) because paper-way it is still the same AFAIK and in-fact they are pushing people to get into the digital realm altogether.

Comment: @shirish The rule is same for paper or digital. I have filed NIL paper returns way back in 2002. There is no difference. In recent times IT Department maybe refusing people with NIL/Non-Taxable returns in paper form as they have to take efforts to type and load this into TIN ... There is also a push towards e-filing.